# How to use a 'Clickpad'

Tags: mouse, touchpad, input

I'm going through `libinput` source and it mentions clickpads at some places. I've a laptop with a touchpad and I've never used a clickpad before. Can anyone explain how a clickpad works, what are the basic mechanics?(from a user POV) For example, left middle and right clicks, scrolls etc. I've searched on net and haven't found anything relating to that matter.

Comment: Completely device- and driver-dependent. Get a DualShock 4, the rectangle on the top is a clickpad.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams You move your finger over touchpad to move the pointer, tap to click, two finger tap to right click, there are buttons for those as well on the bottom. Can a clickpad be described in a similar way?

Comment: Sure, although tapping usually becomes clicking.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Can you elaborate a bit? Preferably as an answer.

Comment: No, because it's device- and driver-dependent.

Comment: Fortunately the question was about libinput, so let's just go with libinput's behavior, which is fairly unified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, a laptop "clickpad" is a touchpad with no visible physical buttons. Instead, the *entire touchpad* itself can be pressed down as a button.

Often, painted lines indicate designated 'button' areas ([like this](https://www.zdnet.com/i/story/62/72/006229/u300s-trackpad.jpg)). Depending on which area you were pressing, libinput will recognize it as a left/right click. This is *mostly* software-defined – libinput itself can decide to e.g. add a middle-click area if it wants to.

([Except for Apple products](https://wayland.freedesktop.org/libinput/doc/latest/clickpad_softbuttons.html), which don't use reserved 'button' areas at all – click type just depends on how many fingers you were pressing. Libinput can work in both modes.)

When not pressing down to click, the same areas still work like a regular, large touchpad (although libinput adds some filtering to prevent accidentally moving the cursor when trying to click).

All touch-only gestures – tap-to-click, scrolling – are the same as in regular touchpads.

- http://who-t.blogspot.com/2015/07/a-short-overview-of-touchpad-devices.html
- https://wayland.freedesktop.org/libinput/doc/latest/clickpad_softbuttons.html